# List files whose last line doesn't contain a pattern

Tags: bash, unix, grep

The very last line of my file should be "#"

if I  `tail -n 1 * | grep -L "#"` the result is `(standard input)` obviously because it's being piped.

was hoping for a grep solution vs reading the entire file and just searching the last line.

Comment: What do you mean by reading the entire file? I doubt the tail command would be any less efficient than grep at such a task. I would assume that the tail command would start its search for the last line at the end of the file rather than at the beginning, using byte offsets to accomplish this

Comment: @genx1mx6, is your goal to return files whose last line contains a `#`, or to search through a single file and confirm that the last line contains a `#`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for i in *; do tail -n 1 "$i" | grep -q -v '#' && echo "$i"; done
```

Comment: perfect, does what I needed. although I switched it up because I realized I had two different conditions `for i in *; do tail -n 1 "$i" | egrep -q -v '(closed)|(#)' && echo "$i"; done`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sed` for that:

```
sed -n 'N;${/pattern/!p}' file
```

The above command prints all lines of `file` if it's last line doesn't contain a pattern.

---

However, it looks like I misunderstood you, you want only to print the file names of the those files where the last line doesn't match the pattern. In this case I would use `find` together with the following (GNU) `sed` command:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec sed -n '${/pattern/!F}' {} \;
```

The find command iterates over all files in the current folder and executes the `sed` command. `$` marks the last line of input. If `/pattern/` isn't found `!` then `F` prints the file name.

The solution above looks nice and executes fast it has a drawback it would not print the names of empty files, since the *last line* will never reached and `$` will not match.

For a stable solution I would suggest to put the commands into a script:

*script.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check whether the file is empty ...
if [ ! -s "$1" ] ; then
    echo "$1"
else
# ... or if the last line contains a pattern
    sed -n '${/pattern/!F}' "$1"
    # If you don't have GNU sed you can use this

    # (($(tail -n1 a.txt | grep -c pattern))) || echo "$1"
fi
```

make it executable

```
chmod +x script.sh
```

And use the following `find` command:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec ./script.sh {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this one-liner:

```
while read name ; do tail -n1 "$name" | grep -q \# || echo "$name" does not contain the pattern  ; done < <( find -type f )
```

It uses `tail` to get the last line of each file and `grep` to test that line against the pattern. Performance will not be the best on many files because two new processes are started in each iteration.